# React native: How to ignore a JSON object if it doesn't exist

Tags: json, react-native

I'm trying to get data out of a Open Weathermap API but it's a dynamic API, for some reason.

To get to the amount of rainfall per three hours you have to go to:

```
json.list[0].rain['3h']
```

Now if it's snowing, the 'rain' turns into

```
json.list[0].snow['3h']
```

I got the code like this:

```
return fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => ({
        temp1: json.list[0].main.temp,
        tempmin1: json.list[0].main.temp_mix,
        tempmax1: json.list[0].main.temp_max,
        weather1: json.list[0].weather[0].main,
        time: json.list[0].dt_txt,
        name: json.city.name,
        rainmillimeter1: json.list[0].rain['3h'],
        snowmillimeter1: json.list[0].snow['3h'],
        wind1: json.list[0].wind['speed'],
        vochtigheid1: json.list[0].main['humidity'],
        luchtdruk1: json.list[0].main['pressure'],
```

But then it gets an Unhandled Promise Rejection, and doesn't load any of the API.
Is there a way to let it ignore either rain or snow, if it doesn't exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ternary operators to check if one of the objects aren't there:

```
rainmillimeter1: (json.list[0].rain) ? json.list[0].rain['3h'] : null,
snowmillimeter1: (json.list[0].snow) ? json.list[0].snow['3h'] : null,
```

Also, **Unhandled Promise Rejection** is usually when a promise fails and there is no error handling using `.catch((e) => {})`. Something you probably should account for incase the API is unreachable at any time.

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch